# How to store huge text in Salesforce record

Tags: attachment, files, search, file-storage, long-text-area

I want to store the content of a small book in a Salesforce record. I want to make the text to be searchable by the Standard Salesforce UI and via Apex and SOSL and display it in Lightning UI.

I know there is a limit to Large Text Fields of 1.6 million characters and even then I would have to split the text into multiple fields which is suboptimal.

Which other options do I have and what would you recommend?

1. I could use **Attachments** but then I guess searching would not work anymore.
2. I could let Admin code store it as **Static Resource**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Files](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_salesforce_files_parent.htm&type=5) are a "successor" to Attachments and bodies of Files are [searchable](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=search_fields_file.htm&type=0). You can also take a look at this [comparison](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_files_differences.htm&type=5) of different options for managing content on SF platform.